# The inverse of a matrix $(AB)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I understand that $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$ but is there is a group of matrices in which for any given invertible matrices
$A$ and $B$ in that group, we have $(AB)^{−1} = A^{−1}B^{−1}$? I was thinking maybe two symmetric matrices but I'm not sure, is there in fact, no such matrices?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, such matrices exist. Note first that for invertible $A,B$ we have $(AB)^{-1} = A^{-1}B^{-1}$ if and only if $AB = BA$. Thus, this comes down to finding a collection of invertible matrices which commute.

The simplest non-trivial set of such matrices is the set of diagonal matrices with all non-zero diagonal entries.

Answer (score 1):

A group $G$ in which $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ for all $a,b\in G$ is abelian. There's plenty of groups of invertible matrices that are abelian.

A very simple example is the group of powers of $A$, where $A$ is an invertible matrix. Another important one is the set of matrices of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & a
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $a$ and $b$ real, $a^2+b^2\ne0$.